# jquery ajax reloading html of entire page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a simple success or failure message from the server upon submission.  I am reaching success on the Ajax call.  However $('#some_div').html(data) is having the whole originating page being returned to it.  Is there something I'm missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.favorite').click(function() {
            var song_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_favorite.php?song_id=' + song_id,
                success: function(data, textStatus, req) {
                    $('#add_to_favorite_'+song_id).html(data);
                },
                error: function(req) { // req = XMLHttpRequest object
                    alert("could not reach the server");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

update: the code on the ajax_favorite.php?song_id=745 page is

```
<?php 
echo "blah blah";
?>
```

Comment: I don´t understood your question, is it that data get the full source code of another page?

Comment: It would help if you showed what your php page returns.

Comment: Personally I'd use an Ajax-specific URL, that only processes, and returns, the relevant portion that you need. Assuming your script is `path_to_script/ajax_favorite.php` have the Ajax navigate to `path_to_script/ajax/ajax_favorite.php`. But I'm kinda lazy, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments helped in my search for the answer to this problem.  It turns out that I was using .htaccess and passing information back and forth to the server through the GET strings.  This caused all manner of problems with the pathing in the jQuery code.  I have since accounted for this in my own back-end code.  For others who are viewing this question.  If you are using jQuery.get().  Make sure that your paths are correct and accounted for if used in combination with .htaccess trickery.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

after the success of the ajax call,the data variable should have whatever you are returning from the server page( ajax_favoriter.php). So you may need to check what it is returning from that page.You can check that by directly going to ajax_favorite.php?song_id=3 page in a browser(type this url in the browser).What you are seeing now in the browser would be the html markup you will see in the div when u load that using the html() method,

Well i am confused with "Whole originating page" .you mean the page where you are calling from  ?

Comment: The page that I am originating the call from is being rerendered and put in the data variable.  I'm wondering why "blah blah" is not being returned.

Comment: Are u sure that your intial page(from where you are making the call) is different that the ajax server page (ajax_favorite.php) ?

Comment: Yes, the page the call is made from is index.php

Comment: i would love to see your files.May be that will help me to findout the root cause

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying the html page is returned in your 'data'?

Pass the dataType to your request (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), for example json, and make sure your ajax_favorite.php?song_id= page returns the json format.

Otherwise the whole html is returned.

Comment: I added dataType: 'html', and still recieved the html from the originating page.

Comment: ah ok.. try to put the full path instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating directly to `ajax_favorite.php?song_id=745` and check if that returns `blah blah`, probably there is some misconfiguration on server redirects that is redirecting the call to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

in your this file ajax_favorite.php?song_id=745
you have to check if if(isset($_GET['song_id']){ is set if not set don't do anything

and make sure you put this code in top of the page content where no html code is used,
and after success of your if conditions you just echo 'success'; message and check it into your jquery success code like this

NOTE: after success echo message you immediately execute exit; command so you will never get all the html in bottom or the page or below your php code i hope this will help u

```
success: function(data) {
   if(data == 'success'){
      $('#add_to_favorite_'+song_id).html(data or put your own message here);
   }
   else{
      soemething error :D
   }
},
```